# Formatting timedelta object python

Tags: python, formatting, timedelta

I wrote this little script to format a timedelta object according to my needs:

```
   def due_format(self):
        time_diff = abs((self.due - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds())
        days = time_diff / 60 / 60 / 24
        hours = time_diff / 60 / 60
        minutes = time_diff / 60
        hours_wo_days = hours - (math.floor(days) * 24)
        minutes_wo_hours = minutes - (math.floor(hours) * 60)
        if (days >= 7):
            self.due_format = '{} Days'.format(int(days))
        elif (hours > 48):
            self.due_format = '{} Days, {} Hours'.format(int(days), int(hours_wo_days))
        elif (hours <= 48 and hours >= 10 ):
            self.due_format = '{} Hours'.format(int(hours))
        elif (hours <= 1):
            self.due_format = '{} Minutes'.format(int(minutes))
        elif (hours < 10):
            self.due_format = '{} Hours, {:.0f} Minutes'.format(int(hours), int(minutes_wo_hours))
```

I'm getting the feeling that my approach makes things overly complicated and wanted to ask you guys if you would've attacked this problem differently. Are there any shortcuts that I could take advantage of? I hope this question is appropriate for SO.

Comment: Could you explain what it is exactly that you find unsatisfactory about your current approach?

Comment: I was just hoping there was an easier / more pythonic way to do it. just wanna learn :)

Comment: Always mention what Python you use. In this case .total_seconds implies 3.2

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html says "New in version 3.2", but you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timedelta instance have attributes .days and .seconds which save a few lines. They also keep the values small, so you can convert to int once early instead of for each string format. This also removes the need for abs() and .floor.